# What is the predominant programming language used for the F35 Lightning II aircraft?

Tags: programming-languages, embedded

I understand ADA was used for the F22. What is the principal language for the software on the F35?

Comment: [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II#Sensors_and_avionics) according to Wiki.

Comment: @Charles: I added a couple tags I thought might be relevant.

Comment: **Ada** is not an acronym, AdaCore explicitly instructs to write _Ada_ and not _ADA_. [source](http://www2.adacore.com/adaanswers/about/ada)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The F-35 Joint Strike Fighter (Lightning II) software was comprised of the following languages (at least according to the source below):

[image]

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20111219004314/http://journal.thedacs.com:80/issue/53/158) | [Source - Alt](https://www.csiac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/2010_03_30_SoftwareQualityReliabilityandErrorPrediction.pdf) (page 38)

This shows:

- 7% Assembly,
- 5% Ada 83,
- 35% C++, and
- 53% C.

I think Wikipedia's statement is slightly incorrect. All *new* development for the F-35 was done in C or C++. According to the source above:

> In almost every case, the same decision to use C or C++ was made except when a large amount of reuse was possible from previous (F-22) developments.

**EDIT** 2016-03-10: The main source is dead and I haven't found a new one.

Comment: I wonder if Rust is used. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 3):

> Unlike previous aircraft, such as the F-22, all software for the F-35
>   is written in C++ for faster code development.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II

Answer (score -1):

The F-35 has high COTS (commercial off the shelf) hardware content which means it's probably limited in it's use of "esoteric" languages.